# Java/JPA Select unique entities

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager

I'm using JPA to store an Entity that has a creation date. I want to select a single Entity per date. I don't care which one, just one for each creation date. I've been trying sub-select clauses but i can't get them to work. Does anyone have any ideas?

Essentially I have the following Entity:

```
@Entity
class E {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date creationDate;
}
```

I want to select the following from the table:

```
ID    DATE
1     3/4/5 <-- SELECT
2     3/4/5
3     4/4/5 <-- SELECT
4     5/4/5 <-- SELECT
5     5/4/5
6     5/4/5
```

As a work around i'm selecting the dates "SELECT DISTINCT(e.creationDate) ..." and then selecting the entities for each date, but there doesn't seem to be a LIMIT ??? so i'm basically having to select the entire table.

Comment: You probably can do that with a min on Id and a join

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `equals()` method of your class `E` to return true on equals dates. And with this in place, put all your entities fetched from the DB without any constraint into a `Set`. The set will take care of eliminating duplicates for you based on the date(since your equals method was written in such a way).

Comment: Nice idea ... but, I'm also storing some binary data in the database and I don't want to retrieve it out just to not use it. maybe I'll need to split the data into multiple tables, but it would only ever be a 1:1 relationship. you've pointed me in the direction of a work around, so thank you, but it doesn't really give me what I want.

Comment: If not the full, you'd anyways load half of those binary data, as that's your requirement. Also, what's wrong with a sub-query which would select the distinct dates and the outer query to fetch entities on that sub-query? I don't see any problem in that.

Comment: I've tried that but it doesn't work, the sub-query gets each unique date, but I can't limit the outer query to select one item per date, so the result is just the entire table.